# Specify MIPS floating-pointer registers in CFI directives

Tags: assembly, mips, dwarf, debug-information

I'm trying to generate a call-frame info about saved FP register on MIPS:

```
  .text

  .cfi_startproc

  addiu $sp, $sp, -4
  .cfi_adjust_cfa_offset 4
  swc1 $f24, 4($sp)
  .cfi_rel_offset $f24, 0

  .cfi_endproc
```

but this results in

```
$ mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc ~/test.S -c
/home/yugr/test.S: Assembler messages:
/home/yugr/test.S:8: Error: bad register expression
```

How can I provide CFI info for FP register?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of these directives to inform regarding the function's stack frame where the incoming values of call-preserved registers have been stored so that they can be restored to the caller's values on a manual unwind?  $f12 is not a call-preserved register, it is an argument register.  It isn't necessary to inform on scratch/argument registers, since they are call-clobbered, they have no value that the caller is expecting.  Maybe try same with $f24 to see if it will take that??  If so, that's a good indication of this.

Comment: @ErikEidt Good point, I've changed to `$f24` to avoid any misconceptions. Although in my case (low-level asm trampolines) I do need to store argument registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple alternative is to use the register's DWARF number explicitly. DWARF number of `$fN` is `N+32` so for code above I'll need to do

```
  .cfi_rel_offset 56, 0
```

Comment: I'm still curious as to why you need to inform on argument registers?  Just b/c they are saved to memory doesn't seem like enough for a trampoline.  Even if that trampoline invokes some regular code that might unwind before transferring to the ultimate target.

Comment: @ErikEidt You are probably right. I developed a habit of inserting CFI directives for all the registers I save/restore but as you pointed out it may not be necessary in this case...